# getting queryset based on attributes from manytomanyfield in referenced object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```py
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modelones = models.ManyToManyField(ModelOne, blank=True)
```

In a view, I want to get a queryset of `ModelOne`s based on attributes of `ModelTwo`. For instance, how might I get a queryset of `ModelOne`s that have a `ModelTwo` with `is_visible` set to `True` referencing them?

To provide an example:

```py
one_one = ModelOne.objects.create()
one_two = ModelOne.objects.create()

two_one = ModelTwo.objects.create()
two_two = ModelTwo.objects.create(is_visible=True)
two_three = ModelTwo.objects.create()

two_two.modelones.add(one_one)
two_two.save()

two_three.modelones.add(one_two)
two_three.save()

queryset = [????]
```

`queryset` would only contain `one_one` because `two_two` has a reference to `one_one` and also has `is_visible` `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter with:

```
ModelOne.filter(modeltwo__is_visible=True)
```

You can filter relations in reverse. It will use the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_query_name) to use in the [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter). If you did not specify that, it will use the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name), and if you did not specify any of the two, it uses the name of the class in *lowercase*.